# Bigger size Like-Button ?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm working on the mobile version of my company's web site. I redesigned everything using CSS mediaqueries and serverside PHP to perfectly fit in the mobile viewport.

One big problem is facebook's like button. 
It is unbelievable small and nearly impossible to click without zooming in. Is there someone with a similar problem? How did you solve this task?

Thanks in advance!